# Git: How to convert an existing `merge` to a `merge --squash`?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, squash, git-squash

I performed multiple `merge` commits but they should have been `merge --squash` instead. The conflict resolution took more than a day so I can't afford to redo the merging by hand.

Is there a way to convert the `merge` to `merge --squash` ?

Comment: maybe abort the merge and restart?

Comment: Have you committed the merge yet?

Comment: @torek yes but we can force push without problem

Comment: @Oswald the merge is finished... And sadly there were too many conflicts to restart.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's worth noting here that `git merge` and `git merge --squash` are closely related, but `git merge --squash` *does not create a merge*.

The phrasing here is very important, particularly the article "a" in front of "merge": "a merge" is a noun, while "to merge" is a verb.  Both commands perform the act of merging.  The difference lies in *how the result is saved*.

It's also worth a quick reminder, in the form of a diagram of commits, of how merges look.  Each round `o` node here represents a commit, with earlier commits towards the left.  Branch names are labels that point to one specific commit (the *tip* commit of a branch).  You might start with this, for instance:

```
...--o--*--o--o   <-- main
         \
          o--o--o   <-- feature
```

You then decide to merge the one specific `feature` branch back into the `main` branch, so you run:

```
$ git checkout main && git merge feature
```

This does a merge (verb) and makes a merge (noun), and the result looks like this:

```
...--o--*--o--o---o   <-- main
         \       /
          o--o--o   <-- feature
```

Git has added one new commit to `main`, and this new commit is a *merge commit*: it points back to both the previous tip of `main`, and also back (and in this case, downward as well) to the still-current tip of `feature`.  (The name `feature` continues to point to the same commit as before.)

What `git merge --squash` does is to modify the last step.  Instead of making a merge commit, it suppresses committing entirely—for no obvious reason—and forces you to run `git commit`.  When you *do* run `git commit`, this makes an *ordinary* commit, instead of a *merge* commit, so that the result looks like this:

```
...--o--*--o--o---o   <-- main
         \
          o--o--o   <-- feature
```

There are two key items here:

- The **contents** of the new commits are the same.  Both new commits are **made from the index** (the *index* is Git's term for "what goes into the next commit you make").  This index is set up by the merge-as-a-verb process.  The *first* parent is the "main-line" commit, from the branch we are on when we do the merge.  The *second* parent is the other commit, the one we just merged.
- The **parent linkages** of the new commits differ.  A real merge has *both* previous commits as its parents, but a "squash merge" has only *one* previous commit as its parent—the "main-line" commit.  This means it does not—it *can* not—remember which commit was merged-in.

In the case of a conflicted (but real) merge, `git merge` cannot make the new commit on its own, so it stops and forces you to resolve the conflicts.  Once you have finished resolving those conflicts, you must manually run `git commit`, just as you must always (for no obvious reason) do with `git merge --squash` and its fake merges.  You can also request that any real merge stop and let you inspect the result, using `git merge --no-commit`.

This leads to the easy method *to turn a real merge into a fake (squash) merge, **as long as the real merge is not yet committed**:*

- For `git commit` to know to make a merge, it relies on a file left behind by the conflicted (or `--no-commit`) merge.  This file is named `.git/MERGE_HEAD`.  (It also leaves behind a file named `.git/MERGE_MSG` although this extra file is harmless.)
- Therefore, you can simply *remove* `.git/MERGE_HEAD` and run `git commit`.  (You may want to remove the MERGE_MSG file as well, once you've written your commit with its message.  Until then you can use it *as* the message, or as its starting point.)  The `git commit` step will no longer know to make a merge commit, and will instead make an ordinary commit—et voila, you have made a squash merge.

---

**If you have already made a real merge commit,** the process may be harder.  In particular, if you have *published* the merge, you must now make everyone who has obtained this merge, take it back.  Otherwise the real merge will return (they are likely to merge it again), or create problems for them, or even both.  If you can do that, though, or if it has *not* been published, you merely need to "shove the merge aside", as it were, and put in a fake merge commit.

Let's redraw what we have, to make some room.  This is the same graph as before, just spread out onto more lines:

```
...--o--*----o----o 
         \         \
          \         o   <-- main
           \       /
            o--o--o   <-- feature
```

What if we could move `main` back up to the top line, then make a new commit?  Well, we would get the following drawing:

```
...--o--*----o----o--o   <-- main
         \         \
          \         o   [abandoned]
           \       /
            o--o--o   <-- feature
```

Note that all the arrows—including the internal commit arrows that the commits use to record history (not shown here as they're too hard to produce in text drawings)—point *leftward*, so there's no knowledge, in any of the top-line commits, of any of the commits below them: those are all "to their right".  Only the bottom-line commits, plus the one we're going to abandon, know anything about the top-line commits.

Moreover, if we're going to abandon the middle-line commit entirely, let's just stop drawing it, and its two merge arrows:

```
...--o--*----o----o--o   <-- main
         \
          \
           \
            o--o--o   <-- feature
```

And look at that: we've just drawn the kind of commit graph we want for one of those fake squash "merge"s.  This is just what we want, *as long as we get the right contents* in our new commit.

But—this is a sort of an exercise; see if you know the answer before plunging on—**where do the contents of a new commit come from?**  The answer is above, in boldface, in the first bullet point.  (If you've forgotten it, go back and check.)

---

Now that you know that `git commit` uses the index to make the new commit, let's consider the real merge commit we have now.  It has contents.  (All commits have contents.)  Where did they come from?  They came from the index!  If we can just somehow get those contents *back into* the index, we're golden.  And in fact, we can: all we have to do is *check out* that commit, with `git checkout`, or *already have it as the current commit*.

Since we just made the new merge commit, we already have the merge commit as the current commit.  The index is clean—if we run `git status`, it says there's nothing to commit.  So now we use `git reset --soft` to *reset* the branch pointer `main` back one step, to get our intermediate drawing.  The `--soft` argument tells Git: "move the branch pointer, but *don't* change the index and work-tree."  So we'll still have the index (and work-tree) from the original merge.  Now we just run `git commit` to make an ordinary commit, supply some appropriate commit message, and we're done: we have a squash merge.  The original merge is now abandoned, and eventually—some time after 30 days, by default—Git will notice that it's no longer used and will remove it.

(To move back one step, you can use `HEAD~1` or `HEAD^`; both mean the same thing.  Hence the command sequence is just `git reset --soft HEAD^ && git commit`, assuming the current commit is the real merge you wish to replace with a fake merge.)

---

The longer method above can be used *even if* you made multiple merge commits.  You will have to decide, though, whether you want multiple fake merges, or one big fake merge.  For instance, suppose you have this:

```
...--o--o---o--o--o   <-- develop
      \  \    /  /
       \  o--o  /   <-- feature1
        \      /
         o----o   <-- feature2
```

Do you want your final picture to look like:

```
...--o--o---o--o--o   <-- develop
      \  \
       \  o--o    <-- feature1
        \
         o----o   <-- feature2
```

where the last *two* commits on `develop` are the two fake (squash) merges, or do you just want one big fake-squash:

```
...--o--o---o--o   <-- develop
      \  \
       \  o--o    <-- feature1
        \
         o----o   <-- feature2
```

where that last commit is the final result?  If you want *two* fake-squashes, you will need to retain both original merge commits long enough to get them into the index and make two ordinary commits from those.  If you just want one big fake-squash of the final merge, that takes only two Git commands:

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD~2 && git commit
```

since we'll retain the *second* merge's index, move back *two* steps, then make the new commit that shoves aside *both* merges.

Again, it's important that none of the *real* merges have been published—or, if they are published, that you convince everyone else who has picked them up, to stop using them.

Comment: I wish I could accept your answer twice. Very clear and useful. Thanks !
Can you detail how to create _two_ fake-squashes ?

Comment: Making both is harder: it requires using raw commit IDs, or making tags that point to more than one original real-merge commit. The general solution *without* using plumbing commands is to make new commits while setting up the index to match each of the desired commit-states. To get a specific commit's state in place, you can empty out the index (`git rm -r .`) and then repopulate it from the other commit without changing branches (`git checkout <commit-specifier> -- .`).